# Pandas Dataframe split starting on a specific column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following Pandas dataframe:

```
       a         b      c         d  Unnamed: 5 
1  43.91 -0.041619  43.91 -0.041619       43.91
2  43.39  0.011913  43.91 -0.041619       43.91
3  45.56 -0.048801  43.91 -0.041619       43.91
4  45.43  0.002857  43.91 -0.041619       43.91
5  45.33  0.002204  43.91 -0.041619       43.91
6  45.68 -0.007692  43.91 -0.041619       43.91
7  46.37 -0.014992  43.91 -0.041619       43.91
8  48.04 -0.035381  43.91 -0.041619       43.91
9  48.38 -0.007053  43.91 -0.04161        43.91
```

And I would like to do divide this dataframe, by calling the name column `d` by name, and get the following output:

df1 =

```
      a         b      c 
1  43.91 -0.041619  43.91
2  43.39  0.011913  43.91
3  45.56 -0.048801  43.91
4  45.43  0.002857  43.91
5  45.33  0.002204  43.91
6  45.68 -0.007692  43.91
7  46.37 -0.014992  43.91
8  48.04 -0.035381  43.91
9  48.38 -0.007053  43.91
```

df2 =

```
          d  Unnamed: 5 
1  -0.041619       43.91
2  -0.041619       43.91
3  -0.041619       43.91
4  -0.041619       43.91
5  -0.041619       43.91
6  -0.041619       43.91
7  -0.041619       43.91
8  -0.041619       43.91
9  -0.04161        43.91
```

Is it possible to achieve this output using pandas library?

Comment: `df1 = df.iloc[:,:4]; df2=df.iloc[:,4:]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If need one DataFrame with excluded `d` column is used [`Index.get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) for positions and selecting by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), for included is used seelcting by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
col = 'd'
df1 = df.iloc[:, :df.columns.get_loc(col)]
df2 = df.loc[:, col:]
print (df1)
       a         b      c
1  43.91 -0.041619  43.91
2  43.39  0.011913  43.91
3  45.56 -0.048801  43.91
4  45.43  0.002857  43.91
5  45.33  0.002204  43.91
6  45.68 -0.007692  43.91
7  46.37 -0.014992  43.91
8  48.04 -0.035381  43.91
9  48.38 -0.007053  43.91

print (df2)
          d  Unnamed: 5
1 -0.041619       43.91
2 -0.041619       43.91
3 -0.041619       43.91
4 -0.041619       43.91
5 -0.041619       43.91
6 -0.041619       43.91
7 -0.041619       43.91
8 -0.041619       43.91
9 -0.041610       43.91
```